# UIView (superview) height is not as per iPhone size,Its slightly small (approx 64) from bottom in swift 4

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, autolayout

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmFDH.png)I have a rare scenario, My ViewController Base View is slightly small from the bottom. I am using TabBarViewController.

Please find image for reference-

[image: View Image]
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: can you share some more detail ?
code or storyboard screen shots of this ViewController

Comment: I have used aksidemenu for side menu and TabBarViewController for tab bar but my all viewcontroller is up from bottom bar.You can look into image there is black space between uiview and tab bar.

Comment: check your autolayout.

Comment: I think you are not setting your bottom constraints.

Comment: Please look image 2 (edited in question) .How to add autolayout.